# Update type of an imported type

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to re-write some types of mongoose.

Here is the type I am trying to fix

```
import {
  MapReduceOptions,
} from "mongodb";
```

This looks something like this

```
export declare interface MapReduceOptions<TKey = ObjectId, TValue = Document> extends CommandOperationOptions {
    out?: 'inline' | { inline: 1;} | {replace: string;} | { merge: string; } | { reduce: string;};
    query?: Document;
    sort?: Sort;
    limit?: number;
    keeptemp?: boolean;
    finalize?: FinalizeFunction<TKey, TValue> | string;
    scope?: Document;
    jsMode?: boolean;
    verbose?: boolean;
    bypassDocumentValidation?: boolean;
}
```

Now,In this I want to change type of **"out", "query" and "sort"**.

I did something like this

```
export type MapReduceOutput =
  | string
  | { inline: 1 }
  | { replace: string }
  | { reduce: string }
  | { merge: string };


export type TsOmitMapReduction<TSchema extends Document, Key = ObjectId> = Omit<MapReduceOptions, "out" | "query" | "sort">

export interface TsMapReduceOptions<TSchema extends Document, Key = ObjectId>
  extends TsOmitMapReduction<ObjectId, TSchema> {
  out?: MapReduceOutput;
  query?: TsFilter<TSchema>;
  sort: TsSort<TSchema>;
};
```

Is this correct? when I cmd + click on `TsOmitMapReduction` I see this

[image]

Comment: It should be `extends TsOmitMapReduction<TSchema, ObjectId>`.

Comment: You also need to pass the schema and id to the original: `MapReduceOptions<ObjectId, TSchema>`.